# PHP JSON Array empty even if the result query is not empty

Tags: php, json

so i have this php script here.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$response = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM groupe_académiques";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    array_push($response, array("ID"=>$row[0], "Nom"=>$row[1]));

}

echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

And the thing is when i try it it's giving me an empty json array, even if the query is returning some rows.
I used the same script for another table and it's working i really don't understand it's like there's no error, how can i solve that? thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, my "hello everyone" didn't show up at the top of my post.

Comment: seems no problem in code. check output by print_r($response);

Comment: Does this `$number_of_rows` result to anything greater than 0?

Comment: Yes it's greater than 0. And here's what i get with print_r:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 16 [Nom] => g1 ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 17 [Nom] => g4 )  
All the results from the table.

Comment: try and display the json error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Ok so i added this : 

$json = json_encode($response);
$error = json_last_error();

var_dump($json, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8);

And the output it : 

bool(false) bool(true)

Comment: I also tried with : json_last_error_msg()
I get this message : Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: it seems your problem is encoding, but looking at the result of you print_r I don't see any non utf-8 characters there.

Comment: You can just read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and enforce an encoding

Comment: I removed some rows from the table that contained characters like "_", it's still not working but now it's showing me No error when i try the last_error_msg() function..

Comment: With the json_last_error() i get JSON_ERROR_NONE and it's still displaying only [] with no results.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Print data using `print_r` because your data not resturns in json format

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$response = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM groupe_académiques";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array("ID"=>$row[0], "Nom"=>$row[1]));
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($response);echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Otherwise your code is correct.

Comment: I already tried to print_r, it's showing me the rows contained in the table correctly.

Comment: then add at the end `$response = json_encode($response);` and if you want again data back then `$response = json_decode($response);`

Comment: also you can try `$response = json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Below Code       


    <?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM groupe_académiques";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$myData=array(); // blank array
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       array_push($myData,$row); // push rows to array $myData
    }
} 

echo json_encode($myData); //get json

?>
```